# Thread.Sleep(-1)

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the use of

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1)
```

I would expect this to throw an exception, as the documentation for Thread.Sleep says this

> The value of timeout is negative and is not equal to Timeout.Infinite in milliseconds, or is greater than Int32.MaxValue milliseconds.

However, the above Thread.Sleep(-1) doesn't throw an exception. When I look at ReferenceSource I see

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static void Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    SleepInternal(millisecondsTimeout);
    // Ensure we don't return to app code when the pause is underway
    if(AppDomainPauseManager.IsPaused)
        AppDomainPauseManager.ResumeEvent.WaitOneWithoutFAS();
}

public static void Sleep(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    long tm = (long)timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
    if (tm < -1 || tm > (long) Int32.MaxValue)
        throw new  ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout",Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegOrNegative1"));
    Sleep((int)tm);
}
```

Which looks like it doesn't throw for a negative timespan, but only a negative timespan less than -1.

And indeed

```
 Thread.Sleep(-2);
```

Does indeed crash.

So what is the special case here of `-1`. What is `Thread.Sleep(-1)` actually doing?

Comment: You have figured out the value of `Timeout.Infinite`.  They could perhaps also have picked Int32.MinValue but -1 is compatible with the OS.  From the WinBase.h SDK header file: `#define INFINITE  0xFFFFFFFF`  The public methods in the framework strongly avoid unsigned parameter types, there are not [CLSCompliant].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value of [`Timeout.Infinite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite(v=vs.110).aspx) == -1.

> `Timeout.Infinite` : A constant used to specify an infinite waiting period, for threading methods that accept an Int32 parameter.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Aah! Thank you! I never realised this. So what is Thread.Sleep(-1) actually doing? Relinquishing control of this thread indefinitely?

Comment: @Stuart I'd venture that `Thread.Sleep(-1)` is probably something you'll never want to do. (i.e. freeze a thread forever). It would be more useful for waits that can be interrupted on synchronization primitives etc. More generally, Thread.Sleep is something I'd only do for a test.

Comment: @Spender, thanks. I'm looking at some code that a colleague wrote and the final line in Main() (it's a console app) is Thread.Sleep(-1). I'm trying to understand their thinking...

Comment: Yeah, even the docs say you probably shouldn't be doing this *You can specify Timeout.Infinite for the millisecondsTimeout parameter to suspend the thread indefinitely. However, we recommend that you use other System.Threading classes such as Mutex, Monitor, EventWaitHandle, or Semaphore instead to sychronize threads or manage resources.*

Answer (score 7):

This is a special case that essentially means "sleep until someone prods you" - which another thread can do by calling `Thread.Interrupt()`. The sleeping thread should then expect to catch a `ThreadInterruptedException`.